What purpose does SMK serve in a DR situation?
I have SQL server 2022 running under domain svc account (mydomain\sqlsvcacc)
I setup linked server, couple of normal dbs, encrypted dbs, logins, roles and permissions.
How to simulate DR I setup a new SQL server with same version and the engine running under the same service account as above. And then on this I restored the system dbs (master/msdb/model).
I'm able to use the linked server, dbs, roles, permissions.
So, what purpose does SMK serve in a DR situation?
